# What is the equivalent of Google Cloud Datalab(jupyter notebook service) managed service provided in Amazon Cloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, google-cloud-datalab

What is the equivalent of Google Cloud Datalab(jupyter notebook service) managed service provided in Amazon Cloud, for usage by Data Analysts/Data Scientists? Is the only option is to build Databricks/Jupyter notebook separately on EC2 cluster in AWS, is there not a managed service in AWS available for this?

Comment: Side note: There's a newer offering in GCP that replaces Google Cloud Datalab. It's called AI Platform Notebooks and is much more user friendly :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/), a fully-managed service that enables data scientists and developers to build, train and deploy machine learning models.

As part of SageMaker documentation, there is a section on running Jupyter notebook apps with [SageMaker notebook instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html).  You may also want to read [How it works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works.html) and [Get Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works.html) sections to understand the complete workflow.